# Setup Scala and Apache Spark with SBT in Intellij

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt

I am trying to run Spark Scala project in IntelliJ Idea on Windows 10 machine.

My build.sbt:

```
name := "SbtIntellSpark1"    
version := "0.1"    
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"    
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.0"
```

project/build.properties:

```
sbt.version = 1.0.3
```

Main.scala:

```
package example

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    val session = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("StackOverflowSurvey")
      .master("local[1]")
      .getOrCreate()
    val df = session.read
    val responses = df
      .option("header", true)
      .option("inferSchema", true)
      .csv("2016-stack-overflow-survey-responses.csv")

    responses.printSchema()
  }
}
```

The code runs perfectly (the schema is properly printed) when I run the Main object as shown in the following image:

[image]

My Run Configuration is as follows:

[image]

The problem is when I run "Run the program", it shows a huge stack of error which is too large to show here. Please see this [gist](https://gist.github.com/placidrod/db53ad879eba6214c4635b8d1f564268).

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: The error when running: `Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Cannot receive any reply from 192.168.1.4:54577 in 120 seconds` hints that it could be an issue with network configuration. Check that nothing is blocking the run process and that the host 192.168.1.4 can be accessed (e.g. you can ping it).

Comment: Thanks Andrey for your response. But I can access the host without trouble.

Comment: Try if you can run the spark-shell from cmd with the same config. I mean `local[1]`. Then try do the same thing as your main code does but in the spark shell in interactive mode. This way you will see at least if the problem is related to IntelliJ or to your Spark in general.